# convert sql top20 expression to sqlalchemy

Tags: sqlalchemy

I wonder how to generate a top 20 events list with sqlalchemy based on ticket sales?

SQL expression:
`SELECT event_id, SUM(count) AS sum FROM ticketDb WHERE datetime < '$dayAfter' and datetime > '$dayBefore' GROUP BY event_id ORDER BY sum DESC LIMIT 20");`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

Just a little update, as I found a solution a while ago:

```
db.session.query(Ticket.event_id, count_).\                  
                filter(Ticket.creation_date > day_before).\
                filter(Ticket.creation_date <= day_after).\
                group_by(Ticket.event_id).order_by(count_.desc()).\
                limit(20).\
                all()
```

Maybe it helps somebody in the future ;)